# In British English should it be "Rockstar Games' products" or "Rockstar Games's products"

Tags: apostrophe

In British English should it be "Rockstar Games' products" or "Rockstar Games's products" to make it possessive?

I would also like to check if the same rule applies if the company name's first word was an adjective

eg. Happy Games

"Happy Games' office" or "Happy Games's office"?

The rule for American English would also be good to know but not essential.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

(I apologise for any other grammatical errors or poor use of English I may have made in the phrasing of this question.)

Comment: ~Happy Games~ is plural, do not add an apostrophe BEFORE the 's'. Whether you add another 's' or just leave the apostrophe is a question of style, some will argue fervently for or against the extra 's'. `Happy Games' office` or `Happy Games's office` or even `Happy Games Office` are all acceptable.

Comment: 'Happy Games' is a proper noun ending in an 's', rather like 'Evans', 'James' or 'Binns'. The usual convention for plurals of such nouns is to add the apostrophe 's' giving Evans's, James's or (the former part of the House of Fraser chain) Binns's but not pronounce the second 's'. However there is the [royal Court of St James's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Court_of_St_James%27s) where the apostrophe _is_ pronounced.